# How to know if Location Service dialog was shown in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, location-services

As I understood, the dialog from the picture below is only shown the first time an app is asking for location. Whatever option user chooses (Allow or Don't Allow), this dialog is not going to be shown to the user again.

- Is there a way to know if Location Services prompt dialog was already shown in iOS?
- I'd also like to write some UI tests, so I need to be able to show this dialog every time a test is being run. Can I do it somehow (by mocking or whatever)?

(Image is taken from [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203033).)

[image: Location Services prompt dialog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for `CLAuthorizationStatus` in this enum you can find a value called `notDetermined` that is returned when the user has not yet made a choice.

```
// User has not yet made a choice with regards to this application
case notDetermined
```

**example**

```
    if(self.locationManager.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined)
    {
        //Do whatever you want here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I could mock `.authorizationStatus` to always return `.notDetermined` state in UI tests (not unit test)?

Comment: I am not sure about this but, at first glance I think that `.autorizationStatus` is a readOnly var and can be only changed by the `CLLocationManager` `requestAlwaysAutorization` method or `requestInUseAutorization` method @lagoman if you have some advances in this topic please let me know